# \mathfrak{g} not showing up properly in resume

Tags: math-mode, resume

I am using document class margin and line

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{resume}
```

and for some reason,

```
 \mathfrak{g}
```

is not showing up properly (it is just showing up as a g).

Can anyone give me an advice on what I need to do to get \mathfrak{g} to show up properly?

Thank you!

Minimal working example:

```
 \documentclass[margin,line]{resume}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{resume}

  \mathfrak{g}
  \mathfrak{b}

  \end{resume}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Please always provide a complete minimal working example. Also please highlight inline code by backticks `\``.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I will edit the above post appropriately.

Comment: It seems that I need to attach a file called resume.cls.tex because one needs this file to make this document, but how do I attach it? If I copy and paste it, it will be long and messy.

Comment: As you can see from CVRadhakrishnan’s answer, your problem does not depend on the use of `resume`. So instead of including the class file, you could also change your MWE to use the `article` class.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to load `amsfonts` package. Also, `\mathfrak{g}` shall be used in math mode, ie., it should be within dollars.

Comment: Thank you-- I should have come here 3+ hours ago, rather than googling! =)

Comment: \usepackage{amssymb} should also be OK.